# Class Redis not found in laravel horizon

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm having problems with redis on calling laravel-horizon to see the events and jobs.

I installed php-redis with this command.

> sudo apt-get install php-redis

Redis it's working because i can login onto `redis-cli` and throw a ping a command. It response is **"PONG"**.

My php version is 7.4.

I'm using BREW to manage the php versions.

I restarted the PC and restated the apache service. I cleared the laravel cache and config with `artisan optimize`

After doing all, when i try to call laravel horizon, it says that `Class Redis not found`

On laravel config `database.php` on redis client is using phpredis, but i can't change this option because the are other people on the proyect.

Thanks

Comment: You can change this option with local env variable like "client” => env(“REDIS_CLIENT”, “phpredis”)

Comment: You say you use brew to manage php versions but also used apt to install the redis extension. Something doesn't seem right with that combination

Comment: When and where do you see "Class Redis not found"? Is this displayed when you run an artisan command, or is it something you are doing on a page of the site? Do you have a local environment as well as a production environment? If so, which are you working from?

Comment: You do not have Redis install on to PHP, to be able to check, you must do `phpinfo()` or do `php -i` on the CLI (I think), and check you have `Redis` in there, if you do not have it, then you are missing the config file, so it is not being included on PHP runtime

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal where you are running the command based on your PHP configurations run `php -m` this will show the list of installed PHP extensions. If the list is missing redis then install redis extension by running `pecl install redis`. If you have multiple php versions then you could install the extension on linux system by running `sudo apt install php8.1-redis`.